# "Corrupt member variable name" in PHP trying to access to a static function

Tags: php, static, runtime-error

"Corrupt member variable name" exception is throw trying to access to a static function:

```
class CachedSettings
{
    static private $c;

    static private function getCacheInstance() 
    {
        if(!isset(self::$c)) self::$c = phpFastCache();
        return self::$c;
    }

    static public function getGroup($groupName) 
    {
        $cache = CachedSettings::getCacheInstance();
        ...
```

I've tried with `self::`, with the same result.
Looks like it's not a very common error. Any idea?

Comment: Is it a `phpFastCache` error? I've never seen this error before.

Comment: Should you be creating a "new phpFastCache()"?

Comment: could be related to [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65967), though I don't imagine it is this code itself that is throwing this error

Comment: It's not the phpFastCache call, I can't even go inside getCacheInstance function. The code was running a few refactorings before...

Comment: @MarioM. - just removed the phpFastCache() call and dumped some text instead and it worked fine. Suggest you try some logging before/after that call to make sure it's failing where you think it's failing.

Comment: try to use `static` instead of `self`

Comment: Can you post the error and the line number?

Comment: It was about the PHP version, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't see anything wrong but you might want to check out your PHP version. They recently released 5.6.x. If your localhost is different version than your server or whatever, this might be the issue.

1. Install PHP 5.6.X:
   `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6`
2. Edit ~/.bash_profile:
   `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile`
3. Add path at bottom of .bash_profile:
   `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`
4. Make bash_profile finalized:
   `source ~/.bash_profile`
5. Double check PHP 5.6.X is working:
   `php -v`

[If you need some more assistance on upgrading](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php)

Hope this helps,

Comment: I preferred to download straight from php.net, but thanks for the instructions anyway

Comment: You got it. What ever floats the boat right!
Honestly it would be nice to have a cronjob that did all this updating if you're working solo. Programs like MAMP and some live servers automatically update their PHP versions and run the latest without you knowing unless you read all the release notes of each version.

Comment: It was a pain in the a**, php.ini between 5.4 in xampp vs 5.6 from the web where completely different.. bad choice :-/
Thanks anyway, but you have to understand I can't execute a strange bash in my server... any I couldn't 'cos coding in Win.